# Azure Functions v2 throws Exception System.AccessViolationException

Tags: function, azure

I have created new vs2017 C# Azure Functions v2 (.NET Core) project with Time trigger.

When I try to run it I got exception:

```
namespace Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Rpc
internal class JobObjectRegistry : IDisposable, IProcessRegistry
{
    public JobObjectRegistry
    {       
        // this line throws exception
        _handle = CreateJobObject(IntPtr.Zero, null); 

System.AccessViolationException: 
'Attempted to read or write protected memory. 
This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
```

What is missing?

Installed vs2017 Version 15.7.4, Storage Emulator UI is running.

Comment: Hi, is your project set to build to 'Any CPU'?

Comment: @JamesDonovan Yes, it is set to use Any CPU.

Comment: I just update latest Azure Functions and Data Tools, now it works.

Comment: Great! sometimes it can be due to references to x86 DLL's but glad to hear all sorted!